# Pivot for Many names in a Cell powercenter informatica

Tags: pivot, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Good day for all! I recently started using PWC, but it doesn't look very much like IMB's DStage... So, i have a CSV archive, i need converte all nick-names in new rows! Example:

Many names separated by comma

[image: 1]

I need this

[image: 2]

I'm try to use a Normalize, Sequences, Expression, Filter and Aggregator... But, I can't do!

If anyone can help me, i'll very glad so! Thank so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java transformation to do this dynamic looping thing.

1. In java transformation(JTX) create 3 input(id, name,nickname) and 3 output(o_id, o_name,o_nickname) with correct data type.
2. Under the Java code tab; Import Package tab Place the below code
   import java.util.*;
   import java.text.*;
3. Under "On InputRow " tab place the following code.

```
String[] words = nickname.split(",");
len=words.length;

for (int i=0;i<len;i++)    //iterate through the array  
{
o_id =id
o_name=name
o_nickname= words[i];
generateRow();  

}
```

4. Save JTX and link output(o_id, o_name,o_nickname) to next transformation.

I have not tested the code so if it fails pls let me know.

**And every tool is a king un till XML, JSON, PDF, TB size table arrives on the battlefield.*

Comment: Good solution man! But, if I have a CSV: One line with 4 nicks and another with 10 other 50.... This solution is not very efficient..

For example, in IBM-DStage I just use a Transform with an internal Loop to solve this, I don't know if PWC has this possibility.. As I said before, I'm starting to use this program now!

But you are a great person! Thanks a lot for the help! Excellent weekend to you!

Comment: not a problem. I posted another solution that you can probably use.